# XSLT transform cross placed tags

Tags: xslt

I'm new to XSLT and I need to transform cross placed tags like:

```
<tabbable>
    <tab name="tabname1"><content1></content1></tab>
    <tab name="tabname2"><content2></content2></tab>
    <tab name="tabname3"><content3></content3></tab>
</tabbable>
```

transform to:

```
<div>
    <ul>
         <li>tabname1</li>
         <li>tabname2</li>
         <li>tabname3</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="baltab">
        <div><transformed-content1/></div>
        <div><transformed-content2/></div>
        <div><transformed-content3/></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately I can't find detailed tutorials for XSLT.

Comment: What version of XSLT are you working with? Also, I don't believe you did not find a tutorial for XSLT while actually _looking_ for it. Did you try googling "XSLT"?

Comment: Yes i did, i found tutorials about basics, and that's all. Now i learning from "code" snippets what is find here in stack and other sites.

Comment: If you know the basics, you should post the XSLT you've come up with so far, even if it does not work. We are not here to code for you, we help you improve your code.

Comment: I have no idea how can i solve this part (what i posted). I writed transform code to generate XUL to a HTML framework. (Transform of other elements,list,buttons,etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simplest as i first think:

Only needs two for-each cycle, with right element selected:

input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <tabbedpane>
    <tab text="tablabel1">
        <label text="tabcontent1"/>
    </tab>
    <tab text="tablabel2">
        <label text="tabcontent2"/>
    </tab>
    <tab text="tablable3">
        <label text="tabcontent3"/>
    </tab>
```

the transform xml:

```
    <xsl:template match="tabbedpane">
<div class="LFT tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <xsl:for-each select="tab">
    <li class="tab_label">
        <xsl:value-of select="@text"/>
    </li>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
    <div class="tabs_holder">
    <xsl:for-each select="tab">
        <div class="single_tab">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
</div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="label">
   <h6>
    <xsl:if test="@id">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>

        <xsl:value-of select="@text"/>
   </h6>
  </xsl:template>
```

and the result is:

```
<div class="LFT tabbable">
     <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
         <li class="tab_label">tablabel1</li>
         <li class="tab_label">tablabel2</li>
         <li class="tab_label">tablable3</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tabs_holder">
        <div class="single_tab">
            <h6>tabcontent1</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="single_tab">
           <h6>tabcontent2</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="single_tab">
            <h6>tabcontent3</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As i needed.

Comment: For future reference you might want to look up the concept of template _modes_, which is the way to define different groups of templates that match the same nodes but do different things to them.